# JavaScript regex problem while working with < and >

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match some emoticon symbols using javascript regex.
The regex doesn't seem to be working for expressions having `>` or `<`

For example, to match `<3` I used `/<3/` but it wouldn't work. It didn't work for `>.<` either. I tried escaping the `</>` symbols, but to no avail.

All other symbols are working correctly. For instance `^_^` with `/\^\_\^/` and `\m/` with `/\\m\//`

What am I possibly missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be HTML encoded `>` and `<` as `&gt;` and `&lt;`.
Try `/(&lt;|<)3/` and `/(&gt;|>)\.(&lt;|<)/`.

Comment: You are right. The above code solved the problem. Thanks! :)
It's interesting though, the HTML is hand-coded only. This knowledge is always going to be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you seeing this on? `'<3'.match(/<3/)` returns truthy for me on Chrome

Comment: as far as I know, js regex is universally the same on all browsers.